# The list of geocodes of villages/cities of India wanted

Tags: data, geocoding

Any relevant information is welcome.
For example, license of the data, where I can find relevant sources, etc.

Comment: please give more infos what you are looking for: list of cities with lat/lon and number of inhabitans? or what else?

Comment: Why is this tagged google maps api?

Answer (score 2):

The only authentic source is [Survey of India](http://www.surveyofindia.gov.in/). We had got revenue village boundaries with the census data attached.

They sell the data topo-sheet wise. So you need to figure out your area of interest and then contact the SOI office for the digital data.

Answer (score 2):

If your application doesn't mind working to a pc which uses an always on internet connection I'd suggest using geopy's reverse [Geocoding](http://code.google.com/p/geopy/wiki/ReverseGeocoding)

If you don't like that solution you can try your country's geonames.org's [geolocation info-dump](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/). Check the readme on how's the information is stored.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.geonames.org/ might be of help.

There is a very detailed description of that data at http://www.geonames.org/about.html.